# How to save and read matrices with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, save, read.csv

I am trying to save and read matrices of different sizes with `pd.to_csv` command. The probleme is that pandas saves matrices in a string form, thus when I read the CSV file I don't retrive the matrices in their numerical form.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

L = []
for Dim in range(3,10):
    L.append(np.random.randint(1,10, (Dim,Dim)))
    
df = pd.DataFrame(L)
```

```
df
```

[image]

```
df.to_csv("matrices.csv", index=False)
read_matrices = pd.read_csv("matrices.csv")
```

```
read_matrices
```

[image]

each line of `read_matrices` is a string, I want them to be numerical matrices (ndarray or pdseries).

I guess it is related with how I save the data, I tried all the options of `pd.to_csv()` without results. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

`\n` appears when `append` is done, probably "vector" objects are converted to "simple". Therefore, I immediately converted the resulting numpy array into a dataframe, and then added it to the desired dataframe. For the data type, I used the [experimental type](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html), because the empty cells of the pandas were filled with nan and the integers in these columns turned into a float.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
for Dim in range(3, 10):
    l = np.random.randint(1, 10, (Dim, Dim))
    dfl = pd.DataFrame(l, dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())
    df = pd.concat([df, dfl], ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv("matrices.csv", index=False)
read_matrices = pd.read_csv("matrices.csv", dtype=pd.Int64Dtype())

print(read_matrices)

-------------------------------------

    0  1  2     3     4     5     6     7     8
0   9  1  9  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
1   3  5  6  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2   6  8  1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3   2  3  2     1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
4   8  4  9     6  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
5   7  1  6     4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
6   2  6  2     4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
7   6  4  2     6     6  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
8   2  3  3     1     1  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
9   4  8  2     8     2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
10  2  4  5     7     3  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
11  7  9  4     2     7  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
12  3  2  2     8     5     2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
13  2  7  5     8     5     4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
14  2  7  2     8     4     4  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
15  3  3  1     1     4     8  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
16  5  3  4     3     3     6  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
17  6  2  7     2     2     2  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
18  4  6  5     8     8     3     6  <NA>  <NA>
19  6  8  1     2     1     4     7  <NA>  <NA>
20  4  4  7     6     1     5     3  <NA>  <NA>
21  6  2  4     5     5     8     2  <NA>  <NA>
22  3  9  1     1     8     9     4  <NA>  <NA>
23  1  6  1     2     5     4     5  <NA>  <NA>
24  2  9  9     9     3     8     4  <NA>  <NA>
25  5  4  5     7     2     2     1     9  <NA>
26  8  6  7     6     1     2     4     2  <NA>
27  6  1  9     1     5     6     1     3  <NA>
28  8  6  8     6     9     8     9     2  <NA>
29  7  7  5     9     9     9     2     3  <NA>
30  1  8  6     7     4     7     6     9  <NA>
31  8  2  6     6     1     2     9     7  <NA>
32  7  6  7     2     5     4     1     3  <NA>
33  4  8  4     7     2     6     1     3     3
34  6  1  5     4     2     1     8     9     5
35  3  6  3     3     9     9     6     9     3
36  5  3  1     9     5     9     2     4     2
37  6  5  8     5     9     5     4     8     4
38  3  2  2     2     4     8     1     3     1
39  7  3  9     2     5     5     2     6     7
40  9  1  8     3     4     9     3     5     6
41  8  3  4     9     8     8     8     1     8
```